# Javascript - Preventing while-waiting loops

Tags: javascript, java, while-loop

In Java, there is a [latch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) that is designed to countdown and fire an event once some condition is satisfied. This latch is designed to prevent while-waiting loops like

`while (objects not loaded) { do nothing}`

Are there equivalent tools in JavaScript?

Comment: You could use `setTimeout`, but I wouldn't specifically recommend it for this purpose.

Comment: Promise is equivalent in Javascript to CountDownLatch in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watch over that even, so that on success or change on that object then the action should take place.[Javascript watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

Comment: Hmm. The docs page says that this feature is only supported in Gecko and should only be used for debugging purposes. Is there a more universal solution?

Comment: If you are using angularJS in place of java script, then definitely there is no issues in using angularJS watch or if you are sure that one event is going to happen specified time then you can use timer in angularJS which will fire the event after that time.

Comment: angular JS has a watch method? I was looking through the docs and I couldn't find one.

Comment: please refer [watch in angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)